Expo and EAS commands fail due to fetch error: ECONNREFUSED
Working with a React Native Expo project, and facing connection issues when running eas commands and npx commands. the request to expo api dev sources fails
ex:
eas login =>
"FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/sdks/51.0.0/native-modules failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 2606:4700::6812:568:443"
 eas build --platform ios --profile development =>
request to https://api.expo.dev/graphql failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 2606:4700::6812:568:443
Error: GraphQL request failed.
I've tried removing the .expo directory from the root of the project and that did nothing.
I've removed node_modules, cleared npm cache, uninstalled/re-installed eas.
Created a new project and saw the same error.

Upgrading the Node version of 18.2 to 20 fixes this issue. There seems to be an update in the latest expo minor release (51.0.37) that updated fetch commands for node 20 that breaks the way node 18 handles the requests.
"expo": "^51.0.37",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.74.5",

